# Compare const and non-const pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers

Compare const and non-const pointers. Is the comparison legal? Any special care for such comparison. Thanks.

Comment: I agree with @SteveWellens: Ask your compiler :-)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "const and non-const pointers"? Normally const-ness prevents almost nothing (except assignment, obviously, and taking an action that discards the `const`); an `int * const` (constant pointer) and an `int *` (non-constant pointer) are really the same. Do you mean "pointers to const and non-const data", as in `const int *` vs. `int *`?

Comment: Also, while you're at it -- can you clarify what you mean by "comparison"? Are you asking about `==` and `!=`, or about `<` and `<=` and so on? (Because the latter have various restrictions even if both pointers are the same.)

Comment: @SteveWellens: That's not always a great way to tell if something is "legal"; the best it can tell you is something like, "there exists a compiler in which this comparison does not always misbehave".

Comment: @ruakh:  If every time you have a question about the C language you reference the technical specification you will not be very productive.

Comment: @SteveWellens: Being less productive is better than being wrong, which is what will happen often if you simply reference your compiler.  Besides, the drop in productivity only happens while you are learning.  Eventually you gain a confidence in what is correct.

Comment: @SteveWellens: Yeah, it's tricky. In the real-world, we always learn from our compilers; that's unavoidable, and not entirely bad. But sometimes we "learn" things that aren't really true (or aren't universally applicable). So in cases where you have a genuine doubt that something is well-defined -- if it seems like the sort of thing that might sometimes work and sometimes not -- then asking the compiler is of limited usefulness. (You should still do it first, before asking here, as part of "research effort". But you might still need to ask.)

Comment: When you've been programming a very long time, like I have, you know that what is on paper (like a specification) doesn't always match reality.  You can whine about it.  You can argue about it.  You can throw a hissy fit.  But the bottom line is that if you are being paid to deliver a product in the real world, you'd better deal with it and deliver.

Comment: @SteveWellens: Oh, absolutely. But you'll note that I never actually advocated consulting the specification, either. ;-) As far as I'm concerned, the important question isn't "does the spec allow it?", it's "does it work consistently in the compilers I need it to?"; and even for that, my experience is that an ounce of testing is often not sufficient. (For C and C++, that is. For many languages the situation is much better in that respect.)

Comment: @SteveWellens: In all that time, did you not also learn that what works today, may not work next year?  If you're pressed for time to deliver a product, fine. Do what you have to do.  But this is a place to learn good, reliable programming practices.  The OP obviously isn't pressed for time to deliver a product, or he wouldn't be asking about something that can obviously be easily tested.  He's got the time to ask, and we've got the time to answer, but you are discouraging that, leading him down the path of assuming that if something works today, it will always work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A pointer to `T` can be implicitly converted into a const pointer to `T`; similarly, a pointer to `T` can be implicitly converted into a pointer to `const T`. The compiler will do either of those conversions, or both, as needed when you try to compare a pointer to a const pointer. There's nothing there that's any more risky than comparing two non-const pointers or two const pointers.

Answer (score -3):

The purpose of const as in

> const char* p

is to promise that you will not change it. In theory, a non-const pointer should never be pointing at the same location in the same code, as a matter of good coding practice that is. In practice, you may end up making something const because it makes your life easier, but it is not really a true const conceptually. In that case you might need to compare. As was mentioned, depending on what compiler you are using and what settings it has, it may or may not like such a comparison. Just in case it might not, force a cast to a non-const before comparing if this is bothering you, like this, for example:

> if ((char*)const_p == non_const_p)